# Errors in image access in srcset

Tags: angular, angular8, angular9

I am working on an angular electron app. I am trying to access the images as follows:

```
 <div class="col-2">
 <img class="mr-2" src="{{ 'file:///' + imagePath + 'icons/myImage.svg'}}" srcset="{{ 'file:///' + imagePath + 'icons/myImage@2x.png 2x','file:///' + imagePath +'icons/myImage@3x.png 3x'}}">
                                            </div>
```

I am getting error: "uncexpected token , at 'icons/myImage@2x.png 2x'," . I think I am giving image path in a wrong way under srcset. But I don't know what is wrong and how to correct it. How can I give correct path in srcset?

Comment: Try `[srcset]="'file:///' + imagePath + 'icons/myImage@2x.png 2x','file:///' + imagePath +'icons/myImage@3x.png 3x'">`. I'm fairly sure that it does not see the `,` as a normal `,` when using it between `{}`

Comment: nops this is also not working

Comment: Ah, I think I might know. What if you put it in an array, as following: `[srcset]="['file:///' + imagePath + 'icons/myImage@2x.png 2x','file:///' + imagePath +'icons/myImage@3x.png 3x']">`